# Me devuelve null en mi método mostrar

Tags: java

Buenas tengo una duda necesito mostrar los datos que almaceno en mi vector de objetos, pero al momento de mostrarlos, solo devuelve null.

```
//CLASE 

public class Contacto {
    private String nombre;
    private String numero;
    private String correo;
    Contacto[] contacto;

    public Contacto(String nombre, String numero, String correo) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public Contacto() {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.numero = "";
        this.correo = "";
    }

    public Contacto(Contacto c) {
        c.nombre = this.nombre;
        c.numero = this.numero;
        c.correo = this.correo;
    }

    public Contacto getContacto(int n) {
        return contacto[n - 1];
    }

    public void setContacto(int n, Contacto contacto) {
        this.contacto[n - 1] = contacto;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public int length() {
        return contacto.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println();
        return "nombre: " + nombre + "\nnumero: " + numero + "\ncorreo: " + correo;

    }
}
package trabajoCelular;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contacto {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String nombre;
    private String numero;
    private String correo;
    Contacto[] contacto;

    public Contacto(String nombre, String numero, String correo) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public Contacto() {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.numero = "";
        this.correo = "";
    }

    public Contacto(Contacto c) {
        c.nombre = this.nombre;
        c.numero = this.numero;
        c.correo = this.correo;
    }

    public Contacto getContacto(int n) {
        return contacto[n - 1];
    }

    public void setContacto(int n, Contacto contacto) {
        this.contacto[n - 1] = contacto;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public void leerC(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < contacto.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Contacto [" + (i + 1) + "]");

        }
    }


    public int length() {
        return contacto.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println();
        return "nombre: " + nombre + "\nnumero: " + numero + "\ncorreo: " + correo;

    }
}


//CLASE MAIN

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaContacto2 {
    static int opcion;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int pos = 0;
    static String Imprime,nombre,cel,correo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Contacto[] c = new Contacto[pos];
        do {
            opcion = menu();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                if (c.length <= pos) {
                    c = new Contacto[pos + 1];
                    agregarContacto(c);

                }
                pos++;

                break;

            case 2:
                modificarContacto();
                break;
            case 3:
                eliminarContacto();
                break;
            case 4:

                verContactos(c);
                c.toString();
                break;
            case 5:
                buscarContacto();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Saliendo...");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.err.println("\t¡¡¡ERROR!!!");
                System.out.println("\n");
                break;
            }

        } while (opcion != 6);

    }

    private static Contacto[] agregarContacto(Contacto[] c) {
        System.out.println();
        Contacto[] temp = new Contacto[0];
        if (c.length == 0) {
            c = new Contacto[1];
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            nombre = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Celular: ");
            cel = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Correo: ");
            correo = sc.next();
            c[0] = new Contacto(nombre, cel, correo);
        } else if (c.length > 0) {
            temp = new Contacto[c.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++) {
                temp[i] = c[i];
            }
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            nombre = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Celular: ");
            cel = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Correo: ");
            correo = sc.next();
            temp[temp.length - 1] = new Contacto(nombre, cel, correo);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i++) {
                c[i] = temp[i];
            }


        }
        return c;
    }

    private static void modificarContacto() {

    }

    private static Contacto verContactos(Contacto[] c) {
        System.out.println();
        Contacto contacto = new Contacto();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            contacto = c[i];
            System.out.println(contacto);

        }
        return contacto;
    }

    private static void eliminarContacto() {

    }

    private static void buscarContacto() {

    }

    private static int menu() {
        System.out.println("\tOPCIONES: \n");
        System.out.println("[1] Nuevo contacto");
        System.out.println("[2] Modificar contacto");
        System.out.println("[3] Eliminar contacto");
        System.out.println("[4] Ver contactos");
        System.out.println("[5] Buscar contactos");
        System.out.println("[6] Salir");
        System.out.print("\tOpción: ");
        opcion = sc.nextInt();
        return opcion;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es algo bastante simple, le estás pidiendo que c lo haga un String, c es un array de apuntadores de objetos Contacto, no una instancia de la clase Contacto, en este caso estás llamando al método `Object.toString();`, no al método `Contacto.toString();`(Override del método `Object.toString();`).

```
        case 4:
            verContactos(c);
            c.toString();
            break;<i>
```

Por ende se está ejecutando el siguiente bloque de código:

`return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

Y esto es lo que causa que retorne `null`, la solución es simplemente recorrer el array c, llamando para cada uno de sus elementos el método `toString()`, que sí se ejecutaría el override de la clase `Contacto`.